# Android ProgressDialog not working.when creating a new activity

Tags: android

i've searched most of the "progressDialog not working" threads here but none of the answers seem to work for me.

I'm trying to create a new activity that calls a method which executes on a different thread (takes up to 30-5o seconds).

```
public class FLActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FLActivity.this, "", 
                                              "Loading...");

        OtherClass.LongDurationMethodWhichStartsAWorkedThread();

        mProgressDiagog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The long duration method is:

```
// in some other class
public static LongDurationMethodWhichStartsAWorkedThread() {
    Runnable r = new FFThread();
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);

    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch  (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've used thread.join() to wait for the worker thread to execute and then continue.

However, no message is displayed.

Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LongDurationMethodWhichStartsAWorkedThread();` will return instantly because starting a thread is not a blocking call. So probably what is happening is that your progress dialog is being shown and then cleared nearly instantly which makes you think that it isn't being shown at all.

instead you should use Thread/Handler or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to implement your long running operation and show the user progress.

[This page has a nice overview](http://xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html) of how to implement it, though it is certainly not the only option, google search for "AsyncTask example" will give you plenty to choose from.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // perform long running operation operation
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For example showing ProgessDialog
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
     */
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim. I read a couple of hours ago that it's not indicated to use AsyncTask for operations that take more than a few seconds. Mine takes more than 30 secs. Do you think that would be a problem?

Comment: I have never seen anything stating that, can you link to where you read it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call thread.join() from the main thread your UI thread is blocked. So it can't show you any dialogs because it is just waiting when your working thread will be completed. I can recommend you two things:

1. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for running heavy operations in background, it's easier than creating own threads and synchronizing them with the UI thread
2. Create all dialogs in [Activity.onCreateDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29) helper method and show them using Activity.showDialog, this will help you to deal with configuration changes.